# Ignore property setting calls during UI element setup

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP I have a `ListView`, for a list of items. The list can be changed via a change of the selection in the `Sizes` list (see `Sizes.SelectedItem` in the XAML below). For the items in the `ListView` I have a `DataTemplate` for each item. The property `Percent` of the items is represented via a `Slider`, which is bound with `Value="{x:Bind Percent, Mode=TwoWay, ...}"`. The `Slider` has its `Maximum` and `Minimum` values set, and as recommended the `Maximum` first. But still, when I select an entry from the `Sizes` list, the `ListView` itemsSource is changed, the setter of `Percent` gets called, and the initial valid values are all falsified and set to the `Minimum`. I now need a way to find out if the setter was called during the setup phase, and can be ignored, or if the setter call came from a real user, modifying the `Slider` position.

XAML code:

```xaml
<ListView x:Name="PropertiesListView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=((face:Collections) Sizes.SelectedItem).FloatPropertyItems, Mode=OneWay}"
          ContainerContentChanging="PropertiesListView_ContainerContentChanging">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="localItems:FloatItem">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Slider x:Name="value" Grid.Column="0"
                            Maximum="{x:Bind Maximum, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Minimum="{x:Bind Minimum, Mode=OneWay}"                                                
                            Value="{x:Bind Percent, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=50}"
                            StepFrequency="0.1" Margin="10,0,10,0"
                            ValueChanged="value_ValueChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything to get informed when the setup began and when it ended: `SelectionChanged, DataContextChanged, ChoosingItemContainer, ManipulationCompleted` and of course `Loaded`. But none of that worked.
The only working solution was with `ContainerContentChanging`, I found a simple solution this way:

```c#
private void PropertiesListView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args) {
    PropertiesLoading = true;
    if (args.Phase >= 1) {
        PropertiesLoading = false;
    } else {
        args.RegisterUpdateCallback(PropertiesListView_ContainerContentChanging);
    }
}
```

And in the item with the `Percent` property for the `Slider`:

```c#
internal double Percent {
    get => ...
    set {
        if (MainPage.PropertiesLoading) {
            // This is the setup phase, ignore that.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```